# firebase: google environment variable not found on mac

Tags: c#, firebase, macos

i am trying to connect to the google firestore. i was able to connect, giving me key.json file as param:

```
FirestoreDb db = new FirestoreDbBuilder { ProjectId = "interiorcircle", CredentialsPath = "/Users/juliustolksdorf/Projects/Interior_Circle/keys/interiorcircle-4f70f209e160.json" }.Build()
```

But i heard its more common to do this via env variable. I tried setting it up wth terminal in .zshenv and also in .bash_profile (both).

Then i also went into terminal and set the variable.

Now, when I set "env" into terminal I am getting this line:

[image]

So it does look like the file is set correctly. But when I try to run my application with:

```
        var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
```

(which is the recommended way)
my debugger hangs for about 5 minutes until it thorws an exception:

One or more errors occurred. (The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.)

So what am I doing wrong here? Im stuck at this for hours now.

EDIT:

I am working with xamarin.forms application. I set the variable in terminal from mac OS, not in console of xamarin.

I tried:

```
var x = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
```

But im being returned "null"

Comment: How are you running the application? Setting the environment variable in one particular terminal won't make it available in other terminals or in IDEs, for example. If you've set it in `.zshenv` you might want to reboot to see if that helps. I suggest adding a logging line right at the start of the app to log the result of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")` - until that's correct, I wouldn't expect it to work. (You might even want to make your application do *nothing* but log that to start with...)

Comment: (I wouldn't expect the debugger to hang for 5 minutes though. I'd expect it to take a few seconds trying to ping the GCP metadata server, but then fail soon after that. If it's really 5 minutes, that's worrying...)

Comment: See my edits, ill eplxain more there

Comment: "I set the variable in terminal from mac OS" - well that's not going to make the environment variable available in the application, unless you start your application from that terminal. I don't know much about the various shells in macos, but this isn't really an issue with the Google libraries at this point - it's a matter of finding where to set an environment variable so that it's available in your debugger.

Comment: Ok, i did it now in vs terminal "export GOOGLE...." and still I am getting null when trying to retrieve it...

Comment: Again, that's only going to change the environment variables within that terminal, not within the parent process which is the IDE.

Comment: Ok, I get it thank you!